# Why can't I over-ride the default template in Django-admin?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am trying to change the base_site.html to have my own branding on my admin site. However, I can't get it to work. I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/). Anyway, here are the steps:

Added the DIRS settings to **settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Made a folder called admin in myapp/templates/ and copied the base_site.html and pasted it there.
Next, I edited **myapp/templates/admin/base_site.html** to look like this:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('MYBRAND Administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

I also copied base.html and pasted it in my admin folder for good measure. Still, it did not work :/

I even made a folder myProject/templates/admin and pasted the 2 html files in it and even then nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong? BTW, I am using Django-1.9.2.

UPDATE:

I even changed the template in django/contrib/admin/templates. I know Im not supposed to do that, but it was just a test. Even then the change did not work. I am honestly stumped :/ Any help is appreciated. Could be a bug in Django btw?

Comment: did you try restarting the 'runserver'?  you config looks like mine. I have it working fine with the templates in 'myproject/templates/admin/base.html' and BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Comment: Hmm I did but even then it did not work. I updated the question.

Comment: browser cache? or do you use virtualenv at all? as changing in the contrib directory would be /django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need replace all text in the template base_site.html:

From:

```
{% block branding %}
  <h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('MYBRAND Administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

To:

```
{% block branding %}
  <h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Your Site Name Here</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

if you dont see the name with this recomendation, you need to try clear the cache bowser or restart your enviroment

--

Look this:

[image]